# Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to type 'NSString' in coercion

Tags: arrays, swift, string

I have a string that outputs:

```
LATITUDE = [String]()
LATITUDE = ["41.87194", "33.4941704", "46.8796822", "31.9685988", "45.253783"]
var custlatt = (LATITUDE as NSString).doubleValue
```

I'm trying to insert the latitude coordinates into the code below:

```
var markerDict: [Int: GMSMarker] = [:]
for i in 0...(POST_COUNT - 1){
                markerDict[i] = GMSMarker()
                markerDict[i]?.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:custlatt[i], longitude: custlong[i])
                markerDict[i]?.title = ""
                markerDict[i]?.icon = UIImage(named: "Pin Red Small")
                markerDict[i]?.snippet = ""
                markerDict[i]?.map = mapView
```

for the var custlatt, Im getting the error "Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to type 'NSString' in coercion"

any help is greatly appreciated, I'm new to swift and I've been stuck for quite a while. thanks in advance!

Comment: If you don't recognise an array then I would suggest you take a break from the coding and read the first 5 or 6 chapters of the [Swift Programming Langeuage](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html) book so you have the basics covered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot *coerce* an array to a single value. But according to the code this is not want you want anyway.

A bridge cast to `NSString` to convert a `String` to `Double` is *unswifty*

The native Swift way to convert an array of strings to an array of double values is

```
let stringLatitudes = ["41.87194", "33.4941704", "46.8796822", "31.9685988", "45.253783"]
let latitudes = stringLatitudes.compactMap(Double.init)
```

And the for loop is *objective-c-ish*, too. In Swift there is the half-open range operator (`..<`) which avoids the `-1` subtraction.

```
for i in 0..<postCount { ...
```

---

Note: Please name variables lowerCamelCase according to the naming convention

Comment: Note that there are 2 arrays and also the for loop from 0 to postCount so `compactMap` could really mess things up

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes, but as the string arrays seem to be literals an out-of-range crash will reveal a design mistake.

Comment: @vadian Thank you so much for the answer, that solved both problems. I'm still learning and I was stuck on that for so long. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the casting inside the for loop, you can't convert an `Array<String>` into an `NSString`.

Also, converting a `String` to a `Double` should not be done via `NSString`, but via the `Double` initialiser.

You should also conform to the Swift naming convention, which is lowerCamelCase for variable names.

```
let latitudes = ["41.87194", "33.4941704", "46.8796822", "31.9685988", "45.253783"].compactMap { Double($0) }
let longitudes = ["42", "33", "23", "45", "6"].compactMap { Double($0) } 

var markerDict: [Int: GMSMarker] = [:]
for i in 0..<postCount {
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    market = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:latitudes[i], longitude: longitudes[i])
    marker.title = ""
    marker.icon = UIImage(named: "Pin Red Small")
    marker.snippet = ""
    marker.map = mapView
    markerDict[i] = marker
}
```

Comment: `0..<postCount - 1` should be `0..<postCount`

Comment: See my comment to vadians answer, compactMap could be dangerous here.